# c# WebRequest HttpBehaviour error

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection, webrequest

I wrote some code:

```
this.req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this._urlNBKIMain);
this.req.Accept = this._accept;
this.req.Headers.Add(this._acceptLanguage);
this.req.UserAgent = this._userAgent;
this.req.Host = this._hostNBKI;
this.req.KeepAlive = this._keepAlive;
this.req.AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate);
this.req.CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer;
ServicePoint servicePoint = this.req.ServicePoint;
PropertyInfo property = servicePoint.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
property.SetValue(servicePoint, 0, null);
this.res = (HttpWebResponse)this.req.GetResponse();
```

But, I got runtime error:

```
System.ArgumentException: It is not possible to convert an object of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Net.HttpBehaviour".
   in System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   in System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   in System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   in System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   in CheckNBKI.GetMainFormNBKI()
```

Help me, please.

Comment: In what line exactly this exception is being thrown?

Comment: @RicardoSilva I imagine it's this line: `property.SetValue(servicePoint, 0, null);`

Comment: Are you trying to run this directly into IIS? If so, try put the pdb file with the compiled assembly. The pdb file will provide you a more detailed exception (including the line where exception is thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set an `enum` to an integer value. You should use the enum instead. Since the `enum` isn't available (it is an internal of the .NET Framework), you could use some tricks to get an instance of the `enum` value:

```
object val = Convert.ChangeType(0, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType));

property.SetValue(servicePoint, val, null);
```

I have had some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565310/getting-enum-value-via-reflection).