# How to pass an enum value to the constructor of a class through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, enums

i have the class:

```
public enum ProviderType { SqlClient, OracleClient};

public class ExternalClass
{
    private string field1;
    private string field2;
    private string EnumsDependance;

    public ExternalClass(string p1, string p2, ProviderType type)
    {
        this.field1 = p1;
        this.field2 = p2;

        if (type == ProviderType.SqlClient)
        {
            this.EnumsDependance = "SQL TYPE";
        }
        else if (type == ProviderType.OracleClient)
        {
            this.EnumsDependance = "ORACLE TYPE";
        }
        else
        {
            this.EnumsDependance = "NO TYPE";
        }
    }
}
```

In my program I need to create an instance of this class using reflection, but must pass the constructor of this class the value of the enum, how should I do this?

The program is in a different project ExternalClass and ProviderType, and it must be read by reflection. Here is my sketch:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //dynamically load assembly from file ExternalDLL.dll
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\temp\ExternalDLL.dll");

        //get type of class ProviderType (enum) from just loaded assembly
        Type providerType = assembly.GetType("ExternalDLL.ProviderType");

        //get type of class ExternalClass from just loaded assembly
        Type externalClassType = assembly.GetType("ExternalDLL.ExternalClass");

        //creating an instance of the class ExternalClass, using reflection
        //constructor -> ExternalClass(string p1, string p2, ProviderType type)
        object externalClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(externalClassType, new object[]{"param1", 
                                                                                                "param2",
                                                                                                "ENUM VALUE" //how should I pass the value?  
                                                                                                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [getting the enum value by reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13378148/996081)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution**

If you have an enum's `Type` and want to create it's instance from it's **name**, do so by using [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can create your external class instance like this:

```
object enumInstance = Enum.Parse(providerType, "SqlClient");
object externalClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(externalClassType, new object[]{"param1", "param2", enumInstance });
```

If you want to create an enum's instance from it's **value**, you can do so by using [`Enum.ToObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
object enumInstance = Enum.ToObject(providerType, 0);
object externalClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(externalClassType, new object[]{"param1", "param2", enumInstance });
```

---

**Why can't I just pass an integer?**

There seems to be some confusion why using `Enum.ToObject` is necessary. This is because an [`Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx) is not an [`Int32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx), nor does it inherit from it *(it couldn't - all structs in .NET are `sealed`)*. The confusion comes from the fact that you can cast an integer to a specific enum, and get it's instance:

```
ProviderType enumInstance = (ProviderType)0; // Works just fine
```

This works because all enums have an [explicit cast operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) from `Int32`. When you do so, internally the enum calls `Enum.ToObject`. When you call `Activator.CreateInstance`, it does not try to perform a cast or conversion, and tries to use the integer value as a parameter to the constructor. And since the class being created doesn't contain a constructor which takes an `int`, you get a `MissingMethodException`.

Also, enums don't even have to be `int` based, they can be a `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int` (default), `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

---

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis You're right, my mistake. I tested it using `MethodInfo` before, which does not need the `Enum.ToObject`.

Comment: @Wazner That's ok, happens to everyone :-) I updated my post with an explanation why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

**By value**

In C# all enumerations have an underlying type, by default this will be `Int32`. You can get the underlying type of the enumeration by calling [`Type.GetEnumUnderlyingType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.type.getenumunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx).

When no value has been explicitly defined for enumeration values, they will be assigned sequentially, so in your case, `SqlClient` will be 0 and `OracleClient` will be 1.

You can convert a value of the underlying type to the enumeration type using [`Enum.ToObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 object oracleClient = Enum.ToObject(providerType, 1); 
 object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(externalClassType, new object[] { "param1", "param2", oracleClient });
```

**By name**

Alternatively, you could use [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the value by the enumeration value name.